# Google play subscription validation api invalid argument error

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-subscription, google-play-developer-api

I'm using googleapis to verify my subscription server side, but I get following error, google documents have no information about this error, can I ask for help if anyone else had faced the same issue.

Method: [https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tokens/{token}](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/purchases/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/tokens/%7Btoken%7D) (GET)

Error Response:
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Your request is invalid for this subscription purchase.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Your request is invalid for this subscription purchase.",
"domain": "androidpublisher",
"reason": "subscriptionInvalidArgument"
}
]
}
}

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, for newly created inapp subscription items, v2 api should be used

[https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptionsv2/tokens/{token}](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/purchases/subscriptionsv2/tokens/%7Btoken%7D)